# flex - programmaticSkin to be used only on certain items

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I've used programmaticSkin to customize an element i use. I would only like to use it on certain occasions. (on some instances - yes and on others no, or use other skin) is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the elements that you do need the skin, you only need to set the 'styleName' property to something (like 'skinnedElement') and then specify the custom skin within the css selector:

```
.skinnedElement
{
   skin-class:path.to.your.CustomProgrammaticSkin;
}
```